# http post request getting 405 error response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting a 405 error posting an http request. I think my endpoint is only allowing GET requests because when inspecting the response headers it says allow: "GET":

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AllVgnItmEstsController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<VgnItmEstSearchDto>>> PostSearchAll(
        VgnItmSearchParams searchParams
    )
    {
        var results = service.SearchAll(
            searchParams.SearchTerm, 
            searchParams.Page, 
            searchParams.PageSize, 
            searchParams.HasEst, 
            searchParams.DiscriminatorTags
            );
        return await Task.FromResult(results);
    }
}
```

It used to be `[HttpGet]` but then I changed it to `[HttpPost]`. So I don't know why it is still allowing only GET.

This is my network request, you can see it says response headers - allow: "GET":

[image]

payload:
[image]

This is the body type being posted. Maybe I need to register it as a web controller body somehow?:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vepo.Application
{
    public interface IVgnItmSearchParams : ISearchParamsEntity
    {
        bool HasEst { get; set; }
        List<DiscriminatorTags> DiscriminatorTags { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct VgnItmSearchParams : IVgnItmSearchParams {
        public VgnItmSearchParams(string searchTerm, int currentPage, int pageSize,  int page, bool hasEst, List<DiscriminatorTags> discriminatorTags)
        {
            this.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.Page = page;
            this.HasEst = hasEst;
            this.DiscriminatorTags = discriminatorTags;
        }
        [Required]
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Page { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool HasEst { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<DiscriminatorTags> DiscriminatorTags { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think this will shed some light on the issue. Since I added the endpoint in this question, now if I do a different http request to another endpoint that used to work - POST /restaurantItmEsts/ I get:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> Vepo.Web.Controllers.RestaurantItmEstsController.PostSearchAll
> (Vepo.Web)
> Vepo.Web.Controllers.RestaurantItmEstsController.PostVgnItmEst
> (Vepo.Web)

I thought that it makes the method name be the end of the url.

When add the endpoint to the request above so I do a POST /restaurantItmEsts/postvgnitmest

I also get 405.

I fixed the

> AmbiguousMatchException

by adding a path to the `HttpPost` which also fixed the 405:

other endpoint that was being called ambiguous:

```
[HttpPost("PostVgnItmEst")]
```

end point in the question:

```
[HttpPost("PostSearchAll")]
```

Comment: Please share your custom `MyPolicy` in your Program.cs file ? Or using AllowAnyMethod and give it a try.

Comment: @JasonPan I don't see the word "MyPolicy" anywhere else in the app other than that attribute. Very strange. Maybe I should remove it. I do have this `app.UseCors(options =>options.AllowAnyOrigin());app.UseCors("AllowAll")`

Comment: @JasonPan I've got this `services.AddControllers(config =>{var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));})`

Comment: Are you using Ajax to call the "PostSearchAll"? If yes, could you please share the code pertaining to it?

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran The front end is Flutter, so I've just posted the network inspection from chrome

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the controller endpoint in the question was conflicting with another endpoint when I tried to do an older http request that used to work, but now throws an ambiguous exception.

I fixed the

> AmbiguousMatchException

by adding a path to both of the `[HttpPost]` declarations which also fixed the 405 (possibly my front end was also sending it in a way that required the `HttpPost` string path parameter resulting in the 405):

Older endpoint, after adding `"PostVgnItmEst"` path:

```
[HttpPost("PostVgnItmEst")]
```

end point in the question, after adding `"PostSearchAll"` path:

```
[HttpPost("PostSearchAll")]
```

And now it is working.